# Java Servlets command line processing

Tags: java, servlets

I have a command line and i want to convert this into a servlet request in a bash script.How can i do this?
For example: >>Command arguments

the http servlet request shud be :
http://localhost:8080/webshell?op="***command***"&args="*arguments*"

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) or [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/).

Note that it's irrelevant that it'll be talking to a servlet. You want to make an HTTP request: the implementation of the server doesn't affect how you make the request.

Answer (score 1):

you can use wget or curl on the CL of mac/linux systems.  Just try

```
wget <url>
```

Comment: if it does what you need it to do sure.  i think wget/curl or more ubiquitous though...